# Chrome saving streamed file as .gz

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, gzip, stream

I have been banging my head against the wall with this odd behaviour on Chrome

I have files stored encrypted on disk in an unnamed, unordered state. when the files are downloaded by the user, the client is redirected to a download handlers (.ashx) the data is loaded into a stream, decrypted and sent to the client. Now this has worked fine until recently,

It works fine on all browsers except chrome where the file is downloaded as a .gz file and is unreadable?

I have stripped out the stream fetching and cryptography parts for brevity (keep in mind this works perfectly on IE, Firefox etc)

```
    Private Function StreamFile(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) As Boolean

    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ClearHeaders()
    context.Response.BufferOutput = False
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & _sFileName & """")
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", _iSize)
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching()
    context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(System.TimeSpan.Zero)

    Dim oInputStream As System.IO.Stream = GetStream()
    Dim oBufferedStream As New BufferedStream(oFileStream, context.Response.OutputStream)
    oBufferedStream.ProcessStreams(True)

    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

    Return True

End Function

Public Class BufferedStream
    Private _oInputStream As Stream
    Private _oOutputStream As Stream
    Private _bBuffer() As Byte
    Public Const DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 8192

    Public Sub New(ByRef oInputStream As Stream, ByRef oOutputStream As Stream)
        _oInputStream = oInputStream
        _oOutputStream = oOutputStream
        _bBuffer = GetStreamBuffer(ToInteger(_oInputStream.Length))
    End Sub

    Public Function ProcessStreams(ByVal bCloseStreams As Boolean) As Boolean

        Dim iRead As Integer = 0
        Dim iStreamLength As Integer = ToInteger(_oInputStream.Length)

        Try
            iRead = _oInputStream.Read(_bBuffer, 0, _bBuffer.Length)
            While iRead > 0
                _oOutputStream.Write(_bBuffer, 0, _bBuffer.Length)
                iRead = _oInputStream.Read(_bBuffer, 0, _bBuffer.Length)
                If iRead < _bBuffer.Length Then System.Array.Resize(_bBuffer, iRead)
            End While

            If bCloseStreams Then
                Close()
            End If
            Return True

        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetStreamBuffer(ByVal iStreamSize As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim iBufferSize As Integer = iStreamSize - 1
        If iBufferSize > DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE Then iBufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
        Dim bBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(iBufferSize) {}
        Return bBuffer
    End Function

End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTTP header from fiddler when the file is downloaded in chrome

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2009 00:01:45 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
content-disposition: attachment;filename="codeKiwi.txt"
Content-Length: 349
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Note that the filename is codekiwi.txt and the contents are some simple plain text, the file gets saved as codekiwi.txt.gz and contains gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself. I turns out that Chrome (and Firefox) REALLY don't like the response.ClearHeaders call, for some reason IE was ok with this, once I removed it the downloads functioned as expected again...